# Is a question about an other language that has a similar grammatical structure as German on topic?

Tags: discussion

German is a language that has peculiar grammatical structures. One of them is the trennbare verben, when I first learned it seemed so strange to me I couldn´t believe it was grammatically correct. I would like to know if anyone knows another language that has this type of structure.

Is it Ok to ask such a question in *German Stack Exchange*? Or is there another Stack Exchange site where this question is more well fitted?

Answer (score 4):

As per our FAQ we love to see and discuss questions on the **German** language. This also includes questions on the history and etymology but they all need to be related to German to be on topic here.

In case you would like to ask a question on a more general scope including questions on grammar structure in languages other than German you may get better answers of people at our fellow beta site on [linguisitcs](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

If however your question is indeed mainly related to German (which may on occasion  also include other Germanic languages) we'd be happy to see you question here.